# How to add remote validation in mvc5 with additional parameters from outer class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In the below example.can I add additional field Id from outer class in remote validation of Name.

```
public class Outerclass
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public InnerClass Inner {get;set;}
}

public class InnerClass
{
  [Remote("IsNameAvail", "CMS", ErrorMessage = "Err", AdditionalFields = "Id")]
  public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Short answer - you can't do it with default functions. You should implement your own validation attribute or use some sort of third party library like fluent validation.

Comment: Short answer, you cant

Comment: Thanks for ur reply...